# iOS - Facebook SDK allowLoginUI not working

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios7, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to get basic user information from facebook, using the following code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if(![[FBSession activeSession] isOpen]){
        NSLog(@"Creating new session");
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:nil
                                       allowLoginUI:NO
                                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {     
                                      [self makeRequestForUserData];                         
                                  }];
    }else{

    }
}

- (void) makeRequestForUserData
{
    [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"user info: %@", result);
            [self.txtDetails setText: [result string]];
            //[[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"error %@", error.description);
        }
    }];
}
```

When closeAndClearToken is commented and allowLoginUI is set to NO or YES no error occurs and I get the data, problem is whether or not somebody is logged into fb, I get the data of last user who logged in. Where as when I uncomment closeAndClearToken I get following error:

> error =         {
>               code = 2500;
>               message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";
>               type = OAuthException;
>           };

Comment: did you registered your app on facebook?

Comment: @BogdanSomlea yes i did

Comment: So I never expected this, but the problem was, I wrote this code in viewDidLoad and putting it into viewDidAppear works fine.

Comment: because in viewDidLoad, your activeSession state, if you just created the session, it not yet open. All this happens because the openActiveSession is running on a diferent thread and is not yet brought back to the mainThread

Comment: please mark this question as resolved

Answer (score 0):

this is a class method, with a completionHandler, where you will get the user. Just call this method anywhere and it should work, if you setup you app on facebook.

```
 + (void)requestFacebookDataWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))handler {

// If the session state is any of the two "open" states when the button is clicked
if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen
    || FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended) {
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
    if (handler) {
        handler(nil);
    }
    // If the session state is not any of the two "open" states when the button is clicked
} else {
    // Open a session showing the user the login UI
    // You must ALWAYS ask for public_profile permissions when opening a session
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"email"]
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
         [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                                 NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
                                                                 NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 if (handler) {
                     handler(user);
                 }
             }

         }];
         DAppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
         [appDelegate sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
     }];
}
```

}

you will also have to add some methods in AppDelegate; but you will find those methods there:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.0 . Hope it will work

Comment: The error i am getting now says: Error for request to endpoint 'me': An open FBSession must be specified for calls to this endpoint.